# Flask - Jinja2 how to output in different <div id/class>

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So I'm outputting data to my template as below (the function will check if each data (an int) is a result for my calculation that yields True/False, then yield the item which is being calculated.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
# doing something here
def get_data():
    for item in generate_list():
        if isResult(item):
            yield True
        else:
            yield False
        yield item
return Response(stream_template('result.html', data=get_data()))
```

in the HTML file i have:

```
<div id="resultfield">
{% for state, id in data: %}
        {% if state == True %}
         <div class='passed'>{{ id }}:{{ state }}</div>
        {% else %}
        <div class='failed'>{{ id }}:{{ state }}</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

My purpose is that if the state is True then the result (as described in CSS) will be colored green, grey otherwise.

For somehow the code doesn't work as it says "TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable".

How can I fix this problem as I'm new to flask and jinja2?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to yield tuples, not yield the boolean, then the item separately:

```
def get_data():
    for item in generate_list():
        yield isResult(item), item
```

Since `isResult()` is already returning a boolean, there is no need for a `if`/`else` test here.

You can simplify your template to:

```
<div id="resultfield">
{% for state, id in data %}
     <div class="{% if state %}passed{% else %}failed{% endif %}">{{ id }}:{{ state }}</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```